# How to pass a parameter to an applet? (secure mode)

Tags: java, php, security, applet

I've been trying to find a proper way to pass some information, such as password, to my applet. Since the code is executed on the client, I don't want to put that information in clear text in the "param".

I'm using php as script to generate the web page. So, I was wondering if there was already some kind of solution/mechanism? If not, I suppose the only way would be to encrypt the password in php, pass it as a param and decrypt in the applet? My only problem would be that the way to decrypt it would be in the client applet as well. For that I suppose that someone could decompile the applet and look for it? Or is it safe enouph?

Anyway, I'm looking for a good solutions, hope there is one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm with Matthew on that I can't see any secure way to do this. Do you absolutely need to send the password to the applet?

Comment: Yup, I absolutely need it. For instance, I want to be able to connect to a ftp server. I've got an interesting solution, but it's not 100% secure.

Comment: Rather send the to-be-ftp'ed files to the server side in HTTP multipart/form-data encoding so that it's in PHP available by `$_FILES` and finally just let the server side handle the FTP without passing passwords around.

Comment: $_FILES is great, but not for large files. The php doesn't use the client side to connect to the ftp, but rather the http to transfert locally the file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea:

The applet can contact the server for the password (let's say using https).
Then connect to the (s)ftp server.

Note that if you're using ftp and not sftp, maybe the password is passed in clear on the network.

Comment: You've got a point. I totally forgot about ftp authentification.

Answer (score 2):

There is no secure way to do this.  Any data the applet has access to the user has access to.  It is quite trivial to decompile Java applets, and even obfuscators only add a little delay.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thought.